# Why does Einstein's equation of relativity exclude space and time?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, mass-energy

Taking $E={m}{c^2}$, we have mass and energy but no space and time. What is the best way of understanding the ways that space and time are passive and therefore unaccountable as mass and energy?

Answer (score 1):

In special relativity, mass / energy has no influence on spacetime.

However, in general relativity, the curvature of spacetime is directly related to energy, or equivalently, mass. The [Einstein field equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations)
$$R_{\mu \nu} - {1 \over 2}g_{\mu \nu}\,R + g_{\mu \nu} \Lambda = {8 \pi G \over c^4} T_{\mu \nu}$$
includes the [stress-energy tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor), which describes the density and flux of energy and momentum in spacetime.

Answer (score 1):

E=m*c**2  is not the defining equation of relativity. The theory is called special relativity and the equation is a [derived part](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity#Relativistic_dynamics_and_invariance) of the results of the theory. It is the result of [Lorenz transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation) on moving systems, which do take care of space and time  in addition to energy.